# Cake PHP 3 debug_kit panel

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-debug-kit

After install CakePHP3 ver. 3.6.2, debug_kit don't show panel. in the log file
"Warning: DebugKit is disabling itself as your host `newtest.my` is not in the known safe list of top-level-domains (localhost,dev,invalid,test,example,local). If you would like to force DebugKit on use the `DebugKit.forceEnable` Configure option."

How i can enable debug panel? Thank's!

Comment: Have you tried adding `'DebugKit' => ['forceEnable' => true]` in your `app.php` configuration?

Comment: it`work! Thank you!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question has already been answered by Greg Schmidt but for clarity for anyone else wondering about this in the future: basically what is happening is CakePHP has determined that the host you are using is unsafe, and has therefore disabled the Debug Kit. CakePHP also provides a workaround for this by providing the `DebugKit.forceEnable` key to override this default behavior. It is recommended that you do this in either `app.php` or, if you have kept the default `app.php` as-is and provided an override file like `app_local.php` as you should, you can do it there as well:

```
'DebugKit' => [
    'forceEnable' => true,
    // other config options
]
```

CakePHP provides a tiny explanation of this in [Their Cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/3/en/index.html#configuration)

Comment: If this solves your problem can you please mark it as 'solved' so that in the future this answer is easy to find for others.

Comment: Link to official docs has moved to: https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/3/en/index.html#configuration

Answer (score 2):

An other way to achieve this would be to do something like this in your bootstrap.php

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
    Configure::write('DebugKit.forceEnable', TRUE);
    Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => TRUE]);
}
```